# Failed build on Travis CI for WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, travis-ci

I have developed a program in C# and WPF which builds on my local computer, but not on Travis CI.

travis ci url : https://travis-ci.org/comwrg/TestCI

Any advice on possible cause?

Comment: ......... What?

Comment: can't understand?

Comment: Not exactly, what is your problem, what are you asking, why did you post that link and where is your code? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for an example in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question isn't too descriptive, I believe what you are asking is why does the build fail.

It seems you are trying to compile a WPF/Universal Windows Application using Travis (line 1105). However, this isn't actually achievable. Travis CI used Mono for it's .NET runtime functionality (see here https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/csharp/). Mono doesn't support WPF or Universal Windows Applications as it is designed to be usable on all operating systems (WPF and Universal Windows Apps use DirectX heavily which isn't available as standard on other types of Operating System).

Maybe look more into other CI distributers such as [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) as they do include MSBuild system.

Comment: Yes, what you said is my want to describe, and  can you  help me change the question title to become more understand easily in that my Eng is so poor. Thanks.

Comment: @comwrg I have updated to question, just waiting on peer review to update it permanently